# table in swipeview not scrollable in vaadin

Tags: java, css, vaadin

I have a swipeview which holds a table. To swipe horizontally to the next view works well.
 But the table is not scrollable on mobile devices.

[image]

I think it depends on the focus, because when you hold one finger on the display and tab with another (on the table), it is possible to scroll. 
To use the .focus() function on the table didn't work.

My vaadin verison is 7.6.6.